# I am trying to use multiple windows, save the data from each window then update the document and save with new name in Python

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have a program written in Python that uses the `PySimpleGUI` module. The code runs and the windows function correctly in the GUI. I can input the data. It also saves as new document and is named correctly. My issue is that the new inputted words don't get replaced in the `Template` document. The words that I need to replace in my document are formatted like this `{{-NAME_}}`. It looks like the data is not being saved. This is my first time posting here so I am not sure if this is following the correct protocol.

My code:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from docx import Document

input_data = {}

def window1():
    layout = [
        [sg.Text("Enter name:"), sg.InputText(key ="-NAME-")],
        [sg.Text("Enter email:"), sg.InputText(key="-EMAIL-")],
        [sg.Button("Next")]
    ]
    window = sg.Window("Window 1", layout)

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
            break
        elif event == "Next":
            input_data["window1"] = {"name": values["-NAME-"], "email": values["-EMAIL-"]}
            window.close()

def window2():
    layout = [
        [sg.Text("Enter age:"), sg.InputText(key="-AGE-")],
        [sg.Button("Submit")]
    ]
    window = sg.Window("Window 2", layout)

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
            break
        elif event == "Submit":
            input_data["window2"] = {"age": values["-AGE-"]}
            window.close()

def update_word_template(template_path, data):
    try:
        document = Document(template_path)
        for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
            for key, value in data.items():
                placeholder = "{{" + key + "}}"
                if placeholder in paragraph.text:
                    paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace(placeholder, value)
        return document
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window1()
    window2()

    template_path = "C:/Users/steve/OneDrive/Documents/Python practice/Scrollable/Template.docx" 
    template_data = input_data.get("window1", {}).copy()
    template_data.update(input_data.get("window2", {}))

    name = template_data.get("name", "Unnamed")
    output_path = f"C:/Users/steve/OneDrive/Documents/Python practice/Scrollable/{name}_modified.docx"

    try:
        modified_document = update_word_template(template_path, template_data)
        modified_document.save(output_path)
print("Text inserted and document saved:", output_path)
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred:", e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window1()
    window2()

    template_path = "C:/Users/steve/OneDrive/Documents/Python practice/Scrollable/Template.docx" 
    template_data = input_data.get("window1", {}).copy()
    template_data.update(input_data.get("window2", {}))

    name = template_data.get("name", "Unnamed")
    output_path = f"C:/Users/steve/OneDrive/Documents/Python practice/Scrollable/{name}_modified.docx"

    try:
        modified_document = update_word_template(template_path, template_data)
        modified_document.save(output_path)
        print("Text inserted and document saved:", output_path)
    except Exception as e:


        print("An error occurred:", e)`

'''
x
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! To help others answer your question, you may want to check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which may even help you solve your problem without asking a question! 
Specifically, pasting your entire code into a question is rarely the right thing to do. Both you and anyone answering the question will have a better time, if you figure out what your code is doing (e.g. via print statements or a debugger), and isolate the problem to a specific part of it, which then you can ask about, ideally with expected/actual output examples.

Comment: My issue is the code runs with no errors just data from input field is not being replaced in new saved document

Comment: Did you intend to have two `if __name__ == "__main__":` blocks?

Comment: Two? i have two windows supply info to doc

Comment: If possible, reduce your code to only the job done in the function `update_word_template`, then to save the document.  tag `DOCX` only.